# How to create `dev_requirements.txt` from `extras_require` section of `setup.cfg` file using `pip-compile` from `pip-tools`?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pip-tools

I use [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) to manage my dependencies and environments which perfectly generates a `requirements.txt` file for my package that consists of a `setup.py` that looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
from setuptools import setup


if "CI_COMMIT_TAG" in os.environ:
    VERSION = os.environ["CI_COMMIT_TAG"]
else:
    VERSION = "0.0.0"

setup(version=VERSION)
```

and a `setup.cfg` like this:

```
...
[options]
python_requires = >=3.7
zip_safe = False
packages = find:
include_package_data = True
install_requires =
    PyYAML
    Cython
    numpy==1.17.5
    pandas==0.25.3
    ...
package_dir=
    foo=bar

[options.extras_require]
testing =
    tox>=3.1.2
    pytest>=3.4.0
coverage =
    coverage
    pytest-cov>=2.5.1
other =
    anybadge
...
```

Running `$ pip-compile --index-url https://foo@bar@gitlab.my.host/api/v4/projects/236/packages/pypi/simple --no-header --allow-unsafe`  yields my package requirements:

```
...
async-timeout==3.0.1
    # via aiohttp
attrs==21.2.0
    # via aiohttp
bcrypt==3.2.0
...
```

But this only includes all the packages from the `install_requires` section of my `setup.cfg` file and not the requirements from `extras_require`. It should work with a `dev_requirements.in` file as described [here](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#workflow-for-layered-requirements) but I would rather only use one configuration file.

How can I create a separate `dev_requirements.txt` from this `extras_require` section of my `setup.cfg` file using `pip-compile` without having to create a `dev_requirements.in` file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging for a while, I found my answer in another [issue](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools/issues/625#issuecomment-819374864):

`$ pip-compile --extra testing --extra other`

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: I have to wait for 2 days but the tab is pinned in my browser :-)

Comment: @CordKaldemeyer is there a way to generate requirements file that only includes requirements for the `testing` but not the packages listed in `install_requires`?